# Angular @Input value is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Passing a value from parent to child. The value that is received in the child component is undefined.

Here is my app.component with a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4wuwd?file=app/app.component.ts)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface ItemsResponse {
   data: any[];
}
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
   ngOnInit() {
      this.getPosts();
      console.log(this.name); // name is undefined
   }
   name;
   results:Array<any> = []; // code changed
   getPosts() {
      this.http.get<ItemsResponse>('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=3')
      .subscribe(res => this.name = res); // code changed
   }
}
```

Here is my hello.component with a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4wuwd?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts), where the data is passed to the child component.
As you can see the name that is passed from parent to child component through Angular's `@Input` decorator is undefined in the constructor.

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'hello',
   template: `<pre>{{name | json}}</pre>`,
   styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
   @Input() name: string;
}
```

and in the hello.component

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'hello',
   template: `<h1>hi</h1><pre>{{name | json}}</pre>`,
   styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
   ngOnInit() {
   console.log('name', this.name); // name is undefined
}
   @Input() name: string;
}
```

Comment: This is async, you need to have the console.log inside the callback: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5qcuno?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: you want this : `<hello *ngIf="name"  [name]="name"></hello>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, your code is asynchronous, so your console.log needs to be inside the subscribe:

```
.subscribe(res => {
   this.name = res
   console.log(this.name);
})
```

Please check this for more info: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Second of all, you want to pass the object to your child, so instead of

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
```

you want to do:

```
<hello [name]="name"></hello>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5qcuno?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**

And since this is asynchronous, `name` will initially be undefined, as it takes some time for response to come. You can use `OnChanges` in child to track when the value arrives. `OnChanges` is fired whenever there is a change in a `@Input` value. So you can conditionally check if the value is there, and when it is, do whatever you need to do with it.

```
ngOnChanges() {
  if(this.name) {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpc1vy?file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: But name in the child component is undefined. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbzdxl?file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: How do i access the name in the hello.component. Updated the question

Comment: Great! Glad to hear :)